# How to use Jquery Templ() with mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a template

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="experience">
    <label for="c${count}">New Thing:</label>
    <input type="text" id="c${count}" name="Fund[${count}].Name" />
    <label for="c${count}">New Thing count:</label>
    <input type="text" id="c${count}" name="Fund[${count}].FundNo" />
</div>
```

to which I add controls dynamically to a div container.

I have a model in my mvc application

```
[Serializable]
public class Step2ViewModel : IStepViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public List<FormTest.Models.Item> Things;
}

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

How do I bind these newly created controls to a model. Does that entail using 
@Html.LabelFor, @Html.TextBoxFor etc in my template?

thanks!

**Edit**:

Just in case the question is open to interpretation - I want to bind dynamically created controls ( which was done using templ() ) to the List in my model when the form is posted.

Comment: please go back to start and use [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)!

Comment: There must be a compelling reason to use a close-to-beta library? What's wrong with templ()?

Comment: close-to-beta? mate, that project (jQuert Template) is done! No more updates, end of story. JsRender close to beta is way more powerful than jQuery Templates and myself and a lot of people use it in production.

Comment: Ok, I think my question description could have been done better - what I'm interested in is AFTER you create your controls, whether using template engine A or B - now they're in a div container - now how to get them in List<T>. More of a model binding than a templating question I think.

Comment: I still don't get what you need, ThulasiRam said what you need to do, now, simply POST that info back to your controller, you will get an array of `Things`, witch .NET will convert to `List`.

Comment: The POST gives me null for the child collection. Do I need a @model IEnumerable<ChildModel> declaration?

Comment: it's all about your object @MikeW you need to specify it as an `array` with it's full path. The info you show does not allow us to figure that out correctly.

Comment: Thanks mate you helped me with that last comment. The name in the array in the jquery template of course needs to match the property name in the code behind model (Fund != Funds). silly error - all working now Thanks! can you post an answer to tick ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using a project that will no longer have more updates and it was never finished.

Boris Moore created a way to continue jQuery template project and it's called **[JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)**. With JsRender you have the power of jQuery Templates, and much much more, like [accessing paths](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/07_paths.html), use of [helper functions](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/09_helper-functions.html), have [no dependency on jQuery](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/20_without-jquery.html) whatsoever, and list goes on and on...

[PluralSight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net) have an entire 3 hours [course just for JsRender](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=jsrender-fundamentals) (so you can see the importance of it), you can start seeing it with a Trial account.

---

**Now regarding your actual issue**

Every time you want to make the .NET framework fill up the Model for you upon submitting a form, you have to make sure that you write the each property as you had an array, so you need to pass the entire full path of your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('#btnAddDiv').live('click', function () {
                var data = [{ 'count': count++}];
                $('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('body');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="experience">
    <label for="c${count}">New Thing:</label>
    <input type="text" id="c${count}" name="Fund[${count}].Name" />
    <label for="c${count}">New Thing count:</label>
    <input type="text" id="c${count}" name="Fund[${count}].FundNo" />
</div>
    </script>

  <input type="button" id="btnAddDiv" value="Add Div" />
```

//adding on div on button click

```
//Or




 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var data = [{ 'count': 1 }, { 'count': 2 }, { 'count': 3}];
                $('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('body');
            });
        </script>
        <script id="template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="experience">
        <label for="c${count}">New Thing:</label>
        <input type="text" id="c${count}" name="Fund[${count}].Name" />
        <label for="c${count}">New Thing count:</label>
        <input type="text" id="c${count}" name="Fund[${count}].FundNo" />
    </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: use this script mainly then only it will work:  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already have the controls adding dynamically. The question refers to the underlying model - ie. POST values - populating public List<FormTest.Models.Item> Things; Thanks anyway.